# Initialize some property of view object without foreach statment

Tags: c#, .net

I have two Collection from Item & ItemView:

Item

```
{  Id, Name, DisplayName, Code, Price }
```

ItemView

```
{  DisplayName, Price }
```

In .net is it possible Initialize ItemViews with Items *without* foreach statement:

```
        foreach (var item in Items)
            itemViews.Add(new ItemView
            {

                DispalyName = item.DisplayName,
                Price = item.Price
            });
```

It mean something like cast, so just exist propery(DisplanyName,Price) fill in itemviews;

```
ItemViews = (ItemViews) Items;
```

Possible? how? i think i need operator overloading.

**Edit:**

Actually problem is my classes change during time, and this change has redunduncy in codes

I find [*Omu.ValueInjecter*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Omu.ValueInjecter/) package, it works for one object but how use it for a collection?

```
 foreach (var item in this._service.GetAll())
           viewItemCats.Add((ItemCatInput)new ItemCatInput().InjectFrom(item));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Item` and `ItemView` have common properties so you can define the common properties in a base class and use inheritance:

```
public class ItemView 
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class Item : ItemView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    ...etc...
}
```

With this approach you can treat any `Item` as an `ItemView`, here are two examples:

```
var itemViews = myListOfItems.Cast<ItemView>();

var myItemView = (ItemView) myItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you described is due to your design.
It certainly looks like a Model-View design problem. I would approach it this way: Have ItemView "wrap" Item and expose properties used to view the item.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class ItemView 
{
    public ItemView(Item item)
    {
        this.item = item;
    }
    public string DisplayName 
    {
        get
        {
            // TODO: make pretty name
            return this.Item.Name + " (" + this.item.Code + ")";
        }
    }
    public decimal Price
    { 
        get { return this.item.Price; }
        set { this.item.Price = value; }  // TODO: add validation
    }

    private Item item;
}
```